# Should wrapping a thread safe object be sufficient to ensure thread safety?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to encapsulate calls to ASP.Net MemoryCache in a class that works with business types.

I wrote this :

```
public interface IMyModelStore 
{
    MyModel RetrieveMyModel(Guid id);
    void StoreMyModel(MyModel obj);
}

public sealed class InMemoryCache : IMyModelStore
{
    public static  InMemoryCache Instance { get; } = new InMemoryCache(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

    private readonly TimeSpan _expiration;

    private readonly CacheItemPolicy _cachePolicy;

    private InMemoryCache(TimeSpan expiration)
    {
        this._expiration = expiration;
        _cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            SlidingExpiration = _expiration 
        };
    }

    public RetrieveMyModel(Guid id)
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(id));

        return (MyModel)MemoryCache.Default.Get(id.ToString());
    }

    public void StoreMyModel(MyModel obj)
    {
        MemoryCache.Default.Add(obj.Id.ToString(), obj, _cachePolicy);
    }
}
```

My feeling is that I don't have to deal with thread safety, because my code is only getting and passing data to MemoryCache which is thread safe.

Am I right ?

The only case, I guess, that may cause troubles is when a thread is calling RetrieveMyModel at the same time another calls StoreMyModel with the same ID.

Comment: Your `InMemoryCache` itself is thread-safe. As you point out, there may be other races with different threads manipulating a `MyModel` at the same time.

Comment: thx @canton7. I slighlty rewrote the last sentence. Your comments suggest I wasn't clear. I wasn't talking about the thread safety of the MyModel object.

Comment: For that, you'd have to see how `MemoryCache` behaves. Your class is just as thread-safe as `MemoryCache` is, no better, no worse.

Comment: There is one potentially risky thing. The implementation of `MemoryCache.Default` for some reason uses not completely thread-safe double-check lock patter so using `MemoryCache.Default` in the code which can call this property from different threads isn't thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is thread safe (currently). No need to add complexity to be thread safe.

> The only case, I guess, that may cause troubles is when a thread is calling RetrieveMyModel at the same time another calls StoreMyModel with the same ID.

`RetrieveMyModel` and `StoreMyModel` are thread safe, some threads can call this methods with same id without risk. Just `RetrieveMyModel`'s return will depend on the order of execution.